# Test services up and running and report while down

Tags: java, url, esb, mq

In my Java client application, I have a web service call which communicates with a server application using MQ/ESB to update data.

Sometime it happens MQ/ESB is down and the data does not update from one application to another, as MQ/ESB is a channel between the client and server applications.

Is there a site or tool which periodically hits the web service url and reports an error via email when it goes down?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom script that fires a curl request periodically and email it based on the response. A simple java program hitting the web service in a loop can also help.

There are monitoring tools like nagios that can be configured and used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Using FreeSiteStatus.com Web-based control panel, enter the URL you wish to monitor (e.g. http://www.yourdomain.com), and select the monitoring interval (e.g. 1 minute). The monitoring interval represents how often we’ll check to see if the website is online and responding properly. The smaller the interval, the more frequently we’ll check your website.

Next, add email, SMS and push contacts to be alerted on outages. We’ll send an email or text message to these contacts any time there is an outage with your URL, so you’ll know instantly if your website goes down.

Features
1.  24 x 7 x 365 Non-Stop Monitoring
2.  Worldwide Monitoring
3.  Downtime Notification
4.  Send Reboot Request to Your Provider during Downtime
5.  Multi-Protocol Support
6.  Uptime & Performance Reports
7.  Push(SMS) Notification